# brackets in C struct syntax

Tags: c, struct

I'm dealing with the following struct:

```
typedef PACKED struct {
   word         len;                 /* # of bytes to log (including len)*/
   word          type;                /* What kind of data is in this pkt */
   qword         time;                /* What time it was generated       */
   byte           data[MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];
} log_mobile_data_type;
```

My question is, what exactly is that last member of the struct?  Is a member with a size equal to MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE, or just 1 (byte)?  And once I read actual data into the "data" member, does the "data" member represent the actual data, or is it just a pointer to it?  Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `sizeof` and check the result? That would answer your question, would it not?

Answer (score 9):

It's a `byte` array of size `MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE`; it's not a pointer, the data is stored directly in the `struct`.

When you copy the `struct` (e.g. by passing it as a normal parameter to a function) also the data will be copied, since it's a part of the `struct`.

(Incidentally, embedding an array into a `struct` in C is the only way to pass an array *by value* to a function)

Answer (score 1):

It represents the actual data. It is an array of `MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE` `byte`s.

Answer (score 1):

The last member is an array of bytes with the size of the array being specified by MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an **array of bytes**, with the size of `MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE`.

If `MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE` were **50**, then data would be an **array of 50 bytes**.

Answer (score 0):

data is an array of byte, with `MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE` elements, its size would be `sizeof(byte) * MAX_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE`. when you access it, it is an inplace array, thus it is the actual data, not a pointer to it (though you can create a pointer to it via `&a.data[0]` or `a.data`)